# How can I get the date range control to act on the created date field (calculated field) and not the actual date field?

Tags: looker-studio

I have multiple [tables](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7189044) in a Google Data Studio report:

***Table 1 (Input)***:

| Name | Date |
| --- | --- |
| Sally | Jan 14, 2022 |
| Mike | Jan 11, 2021 |
| Bob | Jan 12, 2022 |

***Table 2 (Input)***:

| Name | One Year From Date |
| --- | --- |
| Sally | Jan 14, 2023 |
| Mike | Jan 11, 2022 |
| Bob | Jan 12, 2023 |

<sub>***Note***: `One Year From Date` is a calculated field based on the `Date` field: `datetime_add(Date, interval 1 year)`</sub>

When I add a [date range control](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6291067), it filters based on the date that all the calculated fields are based on (`Date` field). For example, if the date range control is from Jan 1, 2022 to Jan 31, 2022, the results are:

***Table 1 (current output)***:

| Name | Date |
| --- | --- |
| Sally | Jan 14, 2022 |
| Bob | Jan 12, 2022 |

***Table 2 (current output)***:

| Name | One Year From Date |
| --- | --- |
| Sally | Jan 14, 2023 |
| Bob | Jan 12, 2023 |

with the desired outcome being:

***Table 1 (expected output)***:

| Name | Date |
| --- | --- |
| Sally | Jan 14, 2022 |
| Bob | Jan 12, 2022 |

***Table 2 (expected output)***:

| Name | One Year From Date |
| --- | --- |
| Mike | Jan 11, 2022 |

How do I get the filter to filter based on the actual date rather than the calculated field original date?

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/fbdabb09-c9e9-41bc-b6bf-e63e7a2c71b8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved by matching the [date range dimension](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9272806#date-range-dimension) field of each table with the respective date field in each table:

## Table 1

- ***Date Range Dimension***: `Date`
- ***Dimension 1***: `Name`
- ***Dimension 2***: `Date`

## Table 2

- ***Date Range Dimension***: `One Year From Date`
- ***Dimension 1***: `Name`
- ***Dimension 2***: `One Year From Date`

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/f9a1258a-94b4-4383-b247-21a3d89eb984) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/132WoNx9Kp6ejYoCVJYiqInxAolM2EqQOrA-YnJOXUyo/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image: 4]